# Change the label notation styles in cut functions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cut, notation

I'm using the set of `ggplot2` functions for creating some binned data in R. The notation style is "(a,b]". I know that's possible to use pre-specified labels. But I like the idea of using the returned numeric labels provided in the default. However, I'd like to change the notation style to something like "a - b". Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rename the levels from `cut` automatically using regex

```
x = runif(100, 0,100)
y = cut(x, breaks = (0:10)*10)
levels(y)
# [1] "(0,10]"   "(10,20]"  "(20,30]"  "(30,40]"  "(40,50]"  "(50,60]"  "(60,70]"  "(70,80]" 
# [9] "(80,90]"  "(90,100]"
levels(y) = sub(".(.+),(.+).", "\\1-\\2"  , levels(y))
# [1] "0-10"   "10-20"  "20-30"  "30-40"  "40-50"  "50-60"  "60-70"  "70-80"  "80-90"  "90-100"
```